# MessageBox is showing multiple times in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to build a code where it will be able to after passing a time span it will display a `MessageBox` to alert the user that he needs to solve the task scheduled by him.

This is the code I got:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetTimeStamp();
}

private void GetTimeStamp()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        bool bDisplayed = false;
        TimeSpan span = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));

        String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}",
            span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);

        row.Cells[3].Value = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss").Trim();

        if (Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[3].Value) >= DateTime.Parse("0:05:00")
            && Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[3].Value) <= DateTime.Parse("0:19:59") 
            && row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim() == "4 - Needs to be solved")
        {

                MessageBox.Show("There is one or more tasks to be solved", "Informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `MessageBox` is displaying multiple times until it gets the `DateTime.Parse("0:19:59")`. I just what it to display the message one time.

How can I solve it?

Comment: _break_ out of the loop

Comment: Timers and MessageBoxes don't like each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply ask the DataRows collection if there is a row that satisfies your conditions using [IEnumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) and then print your messagebox if true.
No explict for required

```
bool result = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridRow>().Any(row => 
    Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[3].Value) >= DateTime.Parse("0:05:00") &&
    Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[3].Value) <= DateTime.Parse("0:19:59") &&
    row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim() == "4 - Needs to be solved");
if (result)
{
    // Of course you should stop the timer to avoid another call to this
    // with the same result and with another MessageBox.
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    MessageBox.Show("You have 1 task to be solved!");
}
```

Comment: What should I put inside of the `< >`, because `DataGridView` does not work

Comment: I don't get it. dataGridView1 is your DataGridView, It contains a collection of DataGridRow. We need to `Cast<DataGridRow>()` to be able to start the enumeration with Any and we pass to it the delegate to check for the true condtion.

Comment: Of course you need to stop the timer. Otherwise it will trigger again the Tick event and your code reenters showing another messagebox and again and again according to your timer interval

Answer (score 2):

Just introduce a `bool` variable. Add it to your **class**.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!m_bDisplayed)
        GetTimeStamp();
}

private void GetTimeStamp()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        TimeSpan span = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));

        String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}",
            span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);

        row.Cells[3].Value = span.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss").Trim();

        if (Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[3].Value) >= DateTime.Parse("0:05:00")
            && Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[3].Value) <= DateTime.Parse("0:19:59") 
            && row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim() == "4 - Needs to be solved")
        {

                MessageBox.Show("There is one or more tasks to be solved", "Informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                m_bDisplayed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, as suggested in the comments:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[3].Value) >= DateTime.Parse("0:05:00")
        && Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[3].Value) <= DateTime.Parse("0:19:59") 
        && row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim() == "4 - Needs to be solved")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have 1 task to be solved!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why introduce a new variable when you could just `break;` beneath the `MessageBox.Show(...)`?

Comment: @JayGould I am just exposing a concept that can be used. In a more complex situation it might be more practical. But in this case `break` is also a good option so I have added it to he answer I provided.

Comment: That's fair, it wasn't an attack I was genuinely curious. I've used both but I wasn't sure if there was a particular reason in this case to use a bool. Cheers for the reply!

Comment: Even if I use `break` it will keep adding `MessageBox`

Comment: @Rekcs Interesting. `break` should terminate the loop. In that case go with the first option. Not sure why the second option would not work.

Comment: @Rekcs Then I am 100% stumped. Both methods are guaranteed to terminate showing a popup message. Perhaps you need to show more context to your code.

Comment: @Rekcs can you post a full, complete sample of code so we can replicate this please? Either should work, if they don't then something else is happening. Are you showing a messagebox outside of the loop you've given in the code above? Step through your code with a debugger and tell us what's happening.,

Comment: @Rekcs You have not copied my example. The `bool` variable needs to be declared  **before** the `foreach` loop and set to `false`. You are declaring it and setting it inside the loop. Wrong. Look at my code. :) And adjust again to use `bDisplayed = true;`.

Comment: I did it now and it does not. I forget to say that this method is inside of a timer and that's probably why the `MessageBox` shows multiple times

Comment: @Rekcs Well ofcourse! Your variable needs to be defined inside the `class` itself ... then. As mentioned, you need to show the context and provide the full picture.

Comment: Does not work too. I've made the changes and the `MessageBox` keep showing every second

Comment: @Rekcs I am afraid I can't help you any more now. Something is going on with your project setup that we are not seeing, or you declared the variable in the wrong place. With the information provided to us my answer would work. So ... sorry ....

Comment: I've executed the code outside of the `Timer` and inside of a `Button` and it only displays one time.

Comment: @Rekcs Yes, but without seeing all of your relevant code, including the declaration of the variable and the invocation of the timer etc. we are a bit blind here.

Comment: @Rekcs It can't be all of your code. You start the timer somehow? You have a dialog and a button. You have more code to your project. Show us where you have declared `m_bDisplayed`. Show us how you start the timer.